# How to UPDATE the readme.txt file in the tags version

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am trying to update the readme.txt file `Tested up to:` in the tags/1.4.1/ folder, as Otto mentioned here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/update-plugin-tested-up-to-version-without-triggering-plugin-update-to-users/

**without bumping the version**

I have successfully updated the trunk/readme.txt file `Tested up to:` but I am not sure how to update the tags/1.4.1/readme.txt file.

~

I edited the file locally. When I right click on the file in tags/1.4.1/ and select TortoiseSVN > there is no option to 'push' or anything else that would suggest updating that file.

When I right click on the readme.txt file in trunk/ and choose TortoiseSVN > Baranch/tag it gives me an error that the file already exists.

If I right click on the readme.txt file in trunk/ and choose SVN Commit there is no option for the tags folder.

If anyone using **TortoiseSVN** to update their **WordPress Plugin** for changing the `Tested up to:`can provide a step by step that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your current tag:

1. Get a working copy that points to `tags/1.4.1/`. To do this, right click on a directory in windows explorer where you want to place your working copy. Then select **SVN Checkout...**. Change the 'URL of repository' to `tags/1.4.1/`. See: [Checking Out A Working Copy](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html)
2. Make your local changes in the working copy you created in previous step.
3. Right click on the folder of your working copy and select **SVN Commit...** Commit your changes in the working copy you worked on in previous step. TortoiseSVN may warn you that you're trying to commit into a tag (which is true) but you can proceed anyway if that's what you want.

... or you can simply remove the tag from the Repository Browser, make your changes elsewhere (in a working copy that points to trunk) and then Branch/Tag again from the aforementioned working copy.

Comment: Sorry, your instructions are not clear. Example "2. Make your local changes" (I already did that). "3. Commit your changes (from where?) ~Committing from trunk goes to the plugins.svn.wordpress.org/my-plugin/trunk ***NOT the /tags***. Committing from tags gives me the error and does not work!  **If you have competed this as part of the 5.5 update, provide a more detailed step by step as to how you did it.

Comment: Commit from where? That's a strange question. Perhaps you're trying to use Subversion with the concepts of some other version control system (git or whatever) in mind. I'll try to improve the instructions anyway.

Comment: Re: Commit from where? If I right click on the TRUNK folder there is a SVN Commit. If I right click on the 1.4.1 version folder in the TAGS folder there is a SVN Commit. That is why I said "Commit from where". Re: your edit, you say "Commit your changes from the working copy" but you are still not being clear enough as to what FOLDER. ~And as I mentioned it doesn't work on the TRUNK or TAGS folder (or the readme.txt file in either one).

Comment: "If I right click on the TRUNK folder there is a SVN Commit". Please start from bullet point #1 and continue to #2 and then#3. It's meant to be a series of consecutive steps.

Comment: Ok, as a noob to TortoiseSVN I had no idea what you meant by "Get a working copy" ...because I thought the trunk/ or tags/1.4.1/ was my working copy. I had to look it up.. I'll update your Answer to make it a little more clear for anyone else who needs this info. Thx!